# GCP Dataproc Runtime error in new version

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

While I am using Dataproc "2.0 (Debian 10, Hadoop 3.2, Spark 3.1)" I am getting below error. But working fine in "1.4 (Debian 10, Hadoop 2.9, Spark 2.4)". Anyone have idea why this error is coming?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 594, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2916, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2916, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 418, in func
  File "./comint_ml_scores-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/scores_eng/eng_nlp_helper.py", line 529, in enrichNLPRawJson_ForAmazonENG
    sentencesCount, totalsentences = getGrammarCount_ForAmazonENG(bulletFeatures, productDescription, richContentText, brandName, country)
  File "./comint_ml_scores-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/scores_eng/copy_quality_amazon_ENG.py", line 34, in getGrammarCount_ForAmazonENG
    tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_check/__init__.py", line 196, in __init__
    self._start_server_on_free_port()
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_check/__init__.py", line 333, in _start_server_on_free_port
    cls._start_local_server()
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_check/__init__.py", line 345, in _start_local_server
    server_cmd = get_server_cmd(cls._port)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_check/__init__.py", line 596, in get_server_cmd
    java_path, jar_path = get_jar_info()
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_check/__init__.py", line 607, in get_jar_info
    java_path = which('java')
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_check/which.py", line 21, in which
    for path in get_path_list():
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_check/which.py", line 33, in _get_path_list
    return os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

Comment: When did you get the error? When creating the cluster or submitting a job? What's the command or code?

Comment: While submitting a job. I am using below command 

spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn --py-files /opt/conda/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/comint_ml_scores-0.0.1-py3.8.egg /home/anshu/comint_job_ml_models-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/src/scores_common/ml_scores.py ....... None ML_ALL NO

Comment: What happens when (1) you use the `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark` command; (2) remove the `--deploy-mode client --master yarn` ? Also, can you please print the process env?

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz I haven't touched env variables. All are defaults one.

Comment: I have tried "--deploy-mode client --master yarn" without these parameter. But the result is same I am getting same problem. Let me know if you require any extra info. Thanks